# 'iss' function in "FinCal" package in 'R'

Tags: employee-stock-options, option-exercise

Following is the 'iss' function in "FinCal" package in 'R'.

iss: calculate the net increase in common shares from the potential exercise of stock options or warrants.

Description:
calculate the net increase in common shares from the potential exercise of stock options or warrants.

Usage:

iss(amp, ep, n)

Arguments:
amp= average market price over the year

ep= exercise price of the options or warrants

n= number of common shares that the options and warrants can be convened into

When  I entered the above function of "FinCal" package in 'R', I got the following result.

iss(amp=4000, ep=3400,n=3400)

[1] 510

I don't understand how is that computed in "FinCal" package in 'R'?

Would any member of this 'personal finance & MONEY' stack exchange explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iss(amp, ep, n) = ((amp - ep) * n ) / amp

For example,

> iss(amp=4000, ep=3400, n=3400) = ((4000 - 3400) * 3400 ) / 4000 = 510

https://github.com/felixfan/FinCal/blob/master/R/iss.R